# JSON response Error Code 201,but it should be 200 in Android HTTP POST

Tags: android, json, http-post

As iam trying to post the result of rating activity. After reading the rating value from the user I am calling the webservice thro HTTP POST and setting JSON object in it. As My webserver needs authentication, iam able to verify that as well.

But real problem is the response code should be 200 but iam receiving 201. Please suggest me where iam going wrong!

Code:

```
        public static String sendJson(final int rating, final String url) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); // For Preparing Message Pool for the child
             HttpResponse response;

            // proxy
            final String PROXY = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
            // proxy host
            final HttpHost PROXY_HOST = new HttpHost(PROXY, 8080);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(mHttpClient.getParams(),
                 10000); //Timeout Limit
            mHttpClient.getParams().setParameter(
                    ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, PROXY_HOST);
            System.out.println("Sending proxy request: " + mHttpClient);
            // mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                String reqUrl = new String(aBaseUrl + url);                  
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(reqUrl);
                post.getParams().setParameter(
                        ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, PROXY_HOST);
                post.addHeader(BasicScheme
                        .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                                userName, password), "UTF-8", false));
                System.out.println("Sending Post proxy request: " + post);
                json.put("rating", rating);

                // json.put("password", pwd);
                // StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "JSON: " +json.toString());

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                System.out.println("JSON VALUE 2222 " + json.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
                // post.setEntity(new
                // ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));

                post.setEntity(se);
                response = mHttpClient.execute(post);
                /* Checking response */

                statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println("Http Execute finish " + statusCode);

                if(statusCode==200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String getResponseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    System.out.println(" Post Response Text from Server : "
                            + getResponseText);


                }

                if (response != null) {
                    // InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    // //Get the data in the entity
                    // HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    // String getResponseText =
                    // EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    // System.out.println(" Post Response Text from Server : "
                    // + getResponseText);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
            }
            Looper.loop(); // Loop in the message queue
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 201 is normal respoinse code that means "Created". Your webservice is reporting a success with it, and it is normal. HTTP spec defines this code. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for that ! But according to my web services specs i must receive 200. Let me know if iam doing everything correct from Android client end ?

Comment: As a rule at Stackoverflow, i do accept your answer;-) .But just need final confirmation of above question !

Comment: As i can see, everything is OK. If the only issue is in response code, i think you should just change your `if` statement to also check against 201 code

Comment: How is your WebServices is created? What is it's backend? What's mean "my web service specs"? Can you show it?

Comment: Webservices are REST and JAVA.  this is the format server is expecting :                                                   **bold** Request header
POST / XXXXXXXXalbum/rest/v1.0/pictures/12345678
Content-Type: application/json
Request body
{
"rating":3
}
Response header
StatusCode: 200 ok

Comment: I do not have access for it, all i have is above mentioned format that was passed onto me for building the app.

Comment: Hmmm.... i think what response code 201 is indicating, what some new entity is created and be specs response must|can contain an URL for a newly created entity. Maybe you are calling some another method whgat is creating something? Or maybe your webservice specs are erroneous or not full?

Comment: Iam not able to figure it out at this point of time, i will come back with an update on this strange behavior. Thanks @olegas for your help. Keep me posted if you come across anything !